# IIS Remote Manager is missing icons for a specific site

Tags: iis-8

I have a developer that came to me with and issue. He is remotely managing one of his sites on one of our development servers and all of a sudden he lost all of the icons in IIS for this specific site..

All other sites display his icons correctly and when I have him test on another computer everything displays correctly.. So what could have gone wrong on his machine? It was working but is now not working.. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.. Never seen this before and cant seem to figure out what caused it to just go away.. There should be so many more options for him.. Plus if you can see he lost the ability to see the folders on this site also.. And it is every site on this server.. But like I said it is just on his computer, he goes to a different computer he has access to everything..

Guess I cant post a picture.. But if you need to see it I can send it to you if you need to see what I am talking about..

Comment: Could it be a permissions issue? Is it only that developer or can other users see the icons fine. Regarding posting a picture, if you provide a link, someone with higher rep usually comes along and edits your post for you.

Comment: Yes its just this Developer.. Everyone else seems to be seeing everything fine.. And like I said he logs into a different machine he sees everything correctly. And verified he is in the same AD group as everyone else.. And it worked before but all of a sudden stopped and started to show nothing for him but one icon..

Comment: I have tried adding the picture different ways, uploading, providing a link and just adding a hyperlink to the image and it wont let me post it saying I cant post pictures.. even as a hyperlink..

Comment: Come to find out he was ignoring the prompt that he was getting saying that there were new versions of the tools to download on his machine that are on the server.. He just hit Cancel instead of selecting them and hitting ok to install the DLL's and enabling them..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come to find out he was ignoring the prompt that he was getting saying that there were new versions of the tools to download on his machine that are on the server.. He just hit Cancel instead of selecting them and hitting ok to install the DLL's and enabling them.